# Computation of McKean–Schrader (MS) variance estimator

Tags: python, r, excel, matlab, statistics

I am attempting to compute the values for "a" and "Z" for McKean–Schrader (MS) variance estimator for median using Excel.

Reference: [McKean–Schrader (MS) variance estimator](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11148358_Statistical_inference_for_a_linear_function_of_medians_Confidence_intervals_hypothesis_testing_and_sample_size_requirements)

So, for example, for N = 10, a = 2 and Z = 2.299 -- from Table 1.

In Excel, a =ROUND((N+1)/2-N^0.5,0) gives the required value of a = 2.

But, how to compute Z?

From equation (2) Z is the point on the standard normal distribution exceeded with probability alpha/2 which is simply a cumulative binomial probability with parameters p=.5 and N.

How to compute Z using =BINOMDIST(k,N,0.5,1) such that, for example, for N = 10, Z = 2.299 and N = 25, Z = 2.021.

Comment: Is that matlab, python, excel or R related ?

Comment: @obchardon -- Essentially statistics related at level 1 and computationally related to either of R, Matlab, Python, or Excel methods in terms of implementation.

Comment: So it's a math question, not a programming question, and has nothing to do with the tagged programming languages, right?

Comment: Not really, to get an output one needs a code, and issue at hand is of not getting a conversion of a statistical equation, essentially logic, which eventually is a coding issue too.